# How to get SOAP webservices to work with ADFS2.0

Tags: asp.net, web-services, single-sign-on, wif, adfs2.0

I'm trying to use asp.net soap webservice with integrated authentication using ADFS2.0.
What changes do i need to make to the webservice such that i can get the identity info from ADFS2.0?

Is there an example anyone can point me to.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF, this lab will walk you through that
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg557872

In particular the exercise 2
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/identitytrainingcourse_webservicesandidentitylab2010_topic4#_Toc258593356

You can also follow the claims identity guide hands on labs
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2011/06/13/claims-identity-guide-hands-on-labs.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what i see all of the examples that are part of the links above seem to depend on WCF. Is there a way i could use a .net soap web service(hosted on IIS) with WIA when using ADFS2.0?